# Can't find typedef of __CFArray

Tags: c, macos, darwin

I want to access MacOSX C functions from Common Lisp via CFFI and need typedefs from header files.

In

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CFArray.h

there is this line:

> typedef const struct __CFArray * CFArrayRef;

Where do I find the definition of __CFArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFArray.c) as it is part of Apple open source code.

```
struct __CFArray {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    CFIndex _count;         /* number of objects */
    CFIndex _mutations;
    void *_store;           /* can be NULL when MutableDeque */
};
```